# Why is GIT deleting all branches of a cloned SVN repo after running git fetch -p origin?

Tags: git, svn, migration, clone

I cloned an SVN repository using `git svn clone --stdlayout`. After cloning the repository I cleaned it up using the [atlassian migration script](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-convert/):

```
java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar ~/svn-migration-scripts.jar clean-git 
  --force.
```

Then I set the new remote and pushed the repository to the new remote GIT server using `git push --all origin`

After trying to clean up some more I also ran `git fetch -p origin` but that deletes **all** original SVN branches:

```
 ...
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/release_II
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/release_III
 ... etc
```

Is this normal for cloned SVN repositories? It seems like the original SVN branches are not real branches in the new GIT repository. Did I forget something during the migration process? The prune command seems very hard to undo. How can we make sure we don't loose these branches if we run (maybe by accident) a similar command in the future?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my SVN branches weren't actually converted to real GIT branches. So the only branches I saw where remote branches pointing to the SVN repo which could not be reached anymore. Therefore running prune, all my branches were removed.

Most svn-git migration tutorials (including [git-book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git)) and tools assume that you can create actual git branches by running `cp -Rf .git/refs/remotes/origin/* .git/refs/heads/` on the cloned repo. However in my case the branches were in a special 'svn' directory: `.git\svn\refs\remotes\origin`.

I modified some bash scripts I found online to the following:

```
# Convert SVN branches to GIT branches
for branch in `git branch -r | grep "origin/[^tags]" | sed 's/ origin\///'`; do
  git branch $branch refs/remotes/origin/$branch; 
done

# Convert SVN tags to GIT tags
for tag in `git branch -r | grep "tags/" | sed 's/ tags\///'`; do
  git tag -a -m"Converting SVN tags" $tag refs/remotes/$tag
done
```

Now I could see all my branches by running `git branch` and tags with `git tag --list`

Add a remote origin, run `git push origin --all` and `git push origin --tags` and you're done.

Comment: This has helped a lot, thank you

In my case too was a non-standard layout with `--trunk=ptl-master/trunk --branches=ptl-master/branches --tags=ptl-master/tags`, where the one repo had many subrepos. I am assuming this is where the migration-tools fails to properly migrate the tags.

Works like a charm from Windows' "Git Bash" and requires no additional tooling to be installed, thanks.